# Install Tiled on Raspberry Pi 4?

Tags: apt, terminal

I am programming using love but I would like to make my levels on a map/tile editor and I found Tiled map editor but can't find out how to download it. I think it doesn't have a repository.
I only found [this website](https://linuxhint.com/how-to-install-tiled-map-editor-on-ubuntu-linux/) on how to download it for ubuntu which is raspberry pi based.

But it uses `add-apt-get-repository` which doesn't work if you could tell me a way to download it or use `add-apt-get-repository` on raspberry it would be appreciated thanks!

Comment: Hello and welcome – Try this command: `sudo snap install tiled --edge`. What's happened?